# How can I print a Maybe?

Tags: haskell, option-type

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char
import Data.Maybe



phoneBook = 
    [("betty", "555-2928")
    ,("bonny", "092-1029")
    ,("pasty", "493-9202")
    ]

findKey :: (Eq k) => k ->  [(k,v)] -> Maybe v
findKey key [] = Nothing
findKey key ((k,v):xs) 
     | key == k = Just v
     | otherwise = findKey key xs

main :: IO()
main = do
    putStrLn "hello"

    putStrLn (show fromMaybe (findKey "penny" phoneBook))
    putStrLn (show fromMaybe (findKey "bonny" phoneBook))
```

==============================================================

```
dictionary.hs:24:22:
    Couldn't match type `Maybe [Char]' with `[Char]'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: Maybe [Char]
    In the return type of a call of `findKey'
    In the first argument of `putStrLn', namely
      `((findKey "bonny" phoneBook))'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn ((findKey "bonny" phoneBook))
```

why my `putStrLn` throw error when I try to print value get from `fromMaybe`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to understand how [`fromMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.2.0.1/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v%3AfromMaybe) works, first. Quoting the documentation,

> The `fromMaybe` function *takes a default value and and `Maybe` value*. If the `Maybe` is `Nothing`, it returns the default values; otherwise, it returns the value contained in the `Maybe`.

So, you need to pass two values to `fromMaybe`, and the first one is the default value to be used, in case the `Maybe` turns out to be `Nothing`. But in your case, you are only passing one argument,

```
fromMaybe (findKey "penny" phoneBook)
fromMaybe (findKey "bonny" phoneBook)
```

You are just passing the actual `Maybe` value to used, the default value is missing. So, change it to something like

```
fromMaybe "Not Found" (findKey "penny" phoneBook)
fromMaybe "Not Found" (findKey "bonny" phoneBook)
```

Now we are fine with the `fromMaybe` part. But, it still is going to fail, if your code is like this

```
show fromMaybe "Not Found" (findKey "penny" phoneBook)
show fromMaybe "Not Found" (findKey "bonny" phoneBook)
```

because, it means that, you are passing three arguments to `show`, namely `fromMaybe`, `"Not Found"` and `(findKey "penny" phoneBook)`. But `show` expects only one value. Quoting the [`show` documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:show),

> **`show :: a -> String`**
>
> A specialised variant of `showsPrec`, using precedence context zero, and returning an ordinary String.

It just expects only value and returns a `String`. So you need to pass just the value returned by `fromMaybe`, like this

```
show (fromMaybe "Not Found" (findKey "penny" phoneBook))
show (fromMaybe "Not Found" (findKey "bonny" phoneBook))
```

Still it will fail, because `putStrLn` expects only one argument, as per [the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStrLn),

> **`putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`**
>
> The same as `putStr`, but adds a newline character.

So, you just need to pass the result of `show` to `putStrLn`, like this

```
putStrLn (show (fromMaybe "Not Found" (findKey "penny" phoneBook)))
putStrLn (show (fromMaybe "Not Found" (findKey "bonny" phoneBook)))
```

Now, it will print,

```
hello
"Not Found"
"092-1029"
```

**Note 1:** If you don't like to have so many brackets, you can use the `$` operator, which does the implicit function application. Quoting the docs of [`$`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-),

> **`($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b`**
>
> Application operator. This operator is redundant, since ordinary application `(f x)` means the same as `(f $ x)`. However, `$` has low, right-associative binding precedence, so it sometimes allows parentheses to be omitted; for example:
>
> ```
>    f $ g $ h x  =  f (g (h x))
> ```
>
> It is also useful in higher-order situations, such as `map ($ 0) xs`, or `zipWith ($) fs xs`.

So, you can simply drop the unnecessary parens and write your code like this

```
putStrLn $ show $ fromMaybe "Not Found" (findKey "penny" phoneBook)
putStrLn $ show $ fromMaybe "Not Found" (findKey "bonny" phoneBook)
```

**Note 2:** In this particular case, since your `fromMaybe` already returns a `[Char]`, you can simply skip `show` and pass the result of `fromMaybe` to `putStrLn`, like this

```
putStrLn $ fromMaybe "Not Found" (findKey "penny" phoneBook)
putStrLn $ fromMaybe "Not Found" (findKey "bonny" phoneBook)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
show fromMaybe (findKey "penny" phoneBook)
```

passes two arguments to `show`: the first is `fromMaybe` and the second is `findKey "penny" phoneBook`.  You need to parenthesize to only pass one:

```
show (fromMaybe (findKey "penny" phoneBook))
```

But there is another problem.  [`fromMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) takes two arguments, and you have only given it one.  Its first argument should be a default value to return if the maybe turns out to be `Nothing`.

Comment: OP may have intended to use `fromJust` instead of `fromMaybe`.

Comment: I'm being a little sneaky, I don't want them to know about that godless "function". :-P

Comment: @BufBills Yes, that is still wrong.  Function application is `f a b` not `f (a (b))`.